# Nanosecond timestamps on a field and on end of "line" are not stored consistently

Tags: questdb

I have a question about timestamps.
Here is a test_table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    ts TIMESTAMP,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP
) timestamp(timestamp)  PARTITION BY DAY;
```

If I save:

```
test_table ,ts=1626652800000000000i 1626745200000000000
```

Both timestamps are in nanoseconds.

I the db I get two different dates saved:

`ts = 53522-01-20T00:00:00.000000Z` (wrong)
`timestamp = 2021-07-22T01:40:00.000000Z` (correct)
Why are they different?
If I save them as microseconds:
`ts = 2021-07-19T00:00:00.000000Z`  (correct)
`timestamp = 1970-01-19T19:52:25.200000Z` (wrong)